# sorting mixed table datas

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have two tables in a MySQL database. First table is `contacts(customer, id)` that stores customers' information. Second table `history(report, nextFollowingDate, customerid)` store the history of a customer contact, along with next following date. A customer can have multiple records with different values for `nextFollowingDate`.

Sample data are as follows.

`contacts` table:

```
customer  id 
a          1
b          2
c          3
```

`history` table:

```
report     nextFollowingDate     customerid
report1     2018/04/23              1
report2     2018/04/25               1
report3     2018/04/22              2
report4     2018/04/26               3
report5     2018/05/30               2
```

I would like to sort customers in contacts table with on the values of `nextFollowingDate` in the ascending order. It would look like follows.

```
customer    nextFollow
1            2018/04/25
2            2018/05/30
3            2018/04/26
```

But I have no way in my mind of doing that.

Comment: Did you try to excute in mysql?

Comment: When you ask questions, please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you do that, the posters who provide answers will find it easy for them to reproduce the scenario, and the answers would be much productive. For a case like this, you could have used [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), which would have been much easy for the people who try to answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customerId, MAX(nextFollowingDate) FROM history GROUP BY customerId
```

is what you are looking for. However, what do you exactly mean by **last following date *ASC*** is not very clear. I have written this answer based on your example result set that you have given as your expectation. Find [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/225f522/2) to see this in action.